# Melhor maneira de usar o Foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Tenho um treco de código, más acredito que não é um dos melhores, pois sou iniciante em programação. Os valores estão vindo duplicados, eu gostaria de saber se a forma que estou realizando o código é correta e como fazer para os valores não se duplicarem:

```
// Percorrendo os Jobs
            foreach ( $asana->getData() as $tasks )
            {   
                // Pegando ID & Incrementado a Conta
                    $ids     = $tasks->id;
                    $exibir  = true;    
                    $jobs++;

                // Pegando detalhes dos Jobs
                    $getTask = $asana->getTask($ids, array('opt_fields' => 'name,completed,assignee_status,created_at,due_on'));
                    $getTask = json_decode($getTask);

                // Percorrendo os dados
                    foreach($getTask as $item)
                    {
                        // Pegando os Jobs Completos & Incompletos
                            if ( $item->completed ) { $jobs_completos ++; }
                            $jobs_incompletos = $jobs-$jobs_completos;

                        // Pegando as datas
                            if ( $item->due_on )
                            { 
                                $datas[] = $item->due_on;
                            }
                            $conta_data     = count($datas, COUNT_RECURSIVE);
                            $conta_sem_data = $jobs-$conta_data;

                    }

                // Jobs do Mês
                    foreach ( $datas as $data ) 
                    {
                        // Recuperando as datas
                            $data     = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($data));
                            $data     = explode("/", $data); 
                            $hoje_dia = date('d'); // Dia
                            $hoje_mes = date('m'); // Mês
                            $hoje_ano = date('Y'); // Ano

                        // Pegando os Jobs do Mês
                            $jobs_mes = 0;
                            if ( $data[1] == $hoje_mes )
                            {
                                echo $data[0]." / ".$data[1]." / ".$data[2]."<br />";
                                $jobs_mes++;
                            }

                    }
            }
```

Acredito eu que não é necessário este tanto de "**Foreach's**" como posso "melhorar" este código?

Comment: O codigo esta bem "amarrado", um `foreach` depende da saida do oturo e etc, sugiro que separe eles em funções e chame cada uma delas em uma função principal.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly pode me dar um exemplo de como criar uma função e chama-lá no **HTML** abaixo de todos os `foreach`? **Não querendo mastigado, mas querendo!**

Comment: E difícil te ajudar sem sabermos o que é o objeto `$asana` e o que pretende fazer com ele. Tem como [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o resultado de `var_export($asana)`?